# If I use a mysql function in a where clause that returns a static value does it get re-evaluated every row?

Tags: sql, mysql

For example,

select * from x where crc=CRC32('Hi')

does the CRC32 function get run every row it checks? If so how could I optimize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you didn't pass row values as arguments it will be evaluated once.

except for this case:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

selecting random row